# What happens when adding 'out' prefix to brackets in the declaration of MutableList?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, prefix, brackets

I have tried the following code:

```
var listHippo: MutableList<Hippo> = mutableListOf<Hippo>()
var listAnimal : MutableList<out Animal> = listHippo
```

I know that this code can cause a problem (if someone will try to add not a Hippo object), but the is being compiled.
When trying to use add method of *listAnimal* variable, i don't get standart add method,but rather i get a method with one parameter with the type **Nothing**.
My question are:
1.Why when trying to get info (ctrl + left click on the mouse) about this method, it takes me to the standart *add* method?
2.How can i add a *Nothing* object to *MutableList* by add method, if *Nothing* doesn't have a construcotr and therefore can be initiated?
Attached a screenshot of what I see in the IDE:
[image]

Comment: You can't add anything to a list of type `MutableList<out Animal>` as the only thing the type system knows about it is that when you read objects they'll be Hippos (and possibly subclasses of it). Why the autocompletion shows that, I don't know exactly, but since `Nothing` doesn't have instances you can't really add anything in there anyway, so the list is safe.

Comment: have you read the documentation? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: @al3c, Why are you saying:  *"as the only thing the type system knows about it is that when you read objects they'll be Hippos"*, if the decaled variable type is :MutableList<**Animal**>? Didn't you mean **Aniaml** or subtype of it?

Comment: @Eitanos30 Sorry meant `Animal`

Comment: @IR42, of course, and still there  are many things i can't understand. Java is much easier :(

Comment: You cannot do that, if you will be then if you added an Animal which is not a Hippo, then you'll get a RuntimeException more specifically ClassCastException when you call get on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, if you will be then if you added an Animal which is not a Hippo, then you'll get a RuntimeException more specifically ClassCastException when you call get on it.

The correct way to do so:

```kotlin
val hippos = mutableListOf<Hippo>()

// Shallow copy all of the elements present in `hippos`
val animals: MutableList<Animal> = hippos.toMutableList()
```

This way if you ever add some thing to animals, the list reference present in `hippos` won't get affected and hence it is valid.